# Is vitamin D a very passive xenogenic factor to major depressive disorder?

Tags: mental-health, depression, pathophysiology, vitamin-d, contributing-factors

Are the biosynthesis, utilisation and catabolism systems of vitamin D, especially the pathways of neural cells' vitamin D response, altered by the pathophysiological condition of major depressive disorder? If so, can antidepressant drugs restore that? (Assume the dietary uptake and ultraviolet exposure are normal.)

Comment: What makes you think it is?

Answer (score -1):

As someone who has been diagnosed with severe vitamin D deficiency, I can tell you from my personal experience that low vitamin D levels almost always makes you feel sad and depressed (we are talking about the chronic type). And since the levels take a lot of months to rise to normal, this lower mood levels start to become a part of your life.

The [vitamin D](https://www.vitamindcouncil.org/health-conditions/depression/) receptors are linked to the areas of the brain associated with depression. 
There have been many [studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2908269/) to prove this is true. A quick google search will point you to many more studies.

Anti-depressant drugs help in most cases, although the doctor should decide more on this. Almost always as the vitamin D level starts to rise, it does take care of this.